# How to set Background Color for Material3 Card in Android Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I try to set the background color for the Material3 Card in Android Jetpack Compose, using the **backgroundColor** parameter.

implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14'

```
// * Card with background color argument
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                //set background color of the card
                backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                content = {
                    Text("Card with background color argument", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge)
                }
            )
```

i got error message : Cannot find a parameter with this name: backgroundColor
[image]

Answer (score 69):

You can do it like this:

```
Card(
    onClick = {},
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

You don't need to go through the modifier, just use **containerColor**.

Comment: You beat me to it:)  When some default Composable has `colors`parameter answer is `XDefaults.xColors(...some colors)` to set colors.

Comment: Lol, you are usually quick as lightning! :)

Comment: I know this color usage, but sometimes in some conditions of views, what ever I put as color it still show some wired color hat not come from my config to it. Any idea why?

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 8):

Other way to do this:

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
    
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = Color.DarkGray, //Card background color
        contentColor = Color.White  //Card content color,e.g.text
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The upside & downside of Material design are here.
If all cards background color is gray, you only need set

```
surfaceVariant = Color.Gray,
```

If need to set a specific background color to a card use
[Code Poet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100593/2537867) or [sdk document](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/CardColors)

Comment: You were absolutely right. I was working with a custom theme and some color was adding a tinted overlay to the Card Color and Bottom Navigation. It was `surfaceVariant`, fixed it!