# How do you change card colors on material3 android when pressed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-card

[How to set Background Color for Material3 Card in Android Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100231/how-to-set-background-color-for-material3-card-in-android-compose)

Piggy backing fro this question. The answers tells how to set a background color.
When material3 card is pressed, it changes color with a ripple effect.
But how can I change the effect color when it is pressed?

`CardDefaults.cardColors(....)` doesn't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Card` with the `onClick` variant uses internally an `indication = rememberRipple()`. This creates and remembers a Ripple using values provided by `RippleTheme`.

You can provide a custom **`LocalRippleTheme`** to override the default behaviour:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides GreenRippleTheme) {
    Card(
        onClick = { /* Do something */ },
        modifier = Modifier.size(width = 180.dp, height = 100.dp)
    ) {
        //Card content
    }
}
```

with:

```
private object GreenRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Green

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleTheme.defaultRippleAlpha(
        Color.Green,
        lightTheme = true
    )
}
```

[image]

---

Otherwise you can use the **`clickable`** modifier:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = 180.dp, height = 100.dp)
        .clickable (
            onClick = { /* Do something */ },
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = rememberRipple(color = Green )
        )
) {
    //Card content
}
```

[image]

---

Finally if you want to modify the background color when the Card is pressed (not the ripple effect) you can use:

```
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val backgroundColor = if (isPressed) Yellow else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant

    Card(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onClick = { /* Do something */ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width = 180.dp, height = 100.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = backgroundColor
        )

    ) {
        //Card content
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "onClick" property of the Card component to change the color when it is pressed. To do this, you can define a state variable to track the current color of the card and toggle it on click. For example:

```
var cardColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.White) }

Card(
    color = cardColor,
    onClick = {
        cardColor = if (cardColor == Color.White) Color.Green else Color.White
    }
    ...
)
```

Alternatively, you can define the ripple color in the Modifier property of the Card component. For example:

```
Card(
    color = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
        // logic to change color
    }).ripple(color = Color.Green),
    ...
)
```

Comment: The first snippet changes the background color of the card when pressed, not the ripple effect color