# How to set custom background color (instead of stroke) for Card in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Tell me how to set a background color for Card (Jetpack Compose). The trouble is, my card is not filled entirely, but it has a stroke:
[look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgBHJ.jpg)
But I wanna fill this card entirely. How to do it?

I tried to fix this problem as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100231/how-to-set-background-color-for-material3-card-in-android-compose), and wrote the code like this:

```
Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Blue1),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 5.dp))
```

The color was called Blue1.

Comment: delete the elevation

Answer (score 0):

To set a background color for a Card in Jetpack Compose and ensure that the card is filled entirely, you can modify the code as follows:

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Blue1, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
    elevation = 5.dp
) {
    // Content of the card
}
```